# Title name pushes graph lower in R

Tags: r, lattice

Here is example:

```
rdata <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000,2,2),v1=rnorm(1000,1,1),v2=rnorm(1000,3,3),
                v3=rnorm(1000,4,4),v4=rnorm(1000,5,5))


library(lattice)
library(gridExtra)    

title1 <- c("","","Title pushes graph down")
title2 <- c("","","Also here graph lower")

plot1 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata,          
main=list(paste(title1[i],sep=""), fontsize=9, col="black"))})
plot2 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {bwplot(~rdata[,i],rdata,    
main=list(paste(title2[i],sep=""), fontsize=9, col="black"))})


l <- lapply(list(plot1, plot2), 
           function(i) do.call(arrangeGrob, c(i, nrow=1, ncol=3)))

do.call(grid.arrange, l)
```

How to avoid the graph being lower as the graph without title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
title1 <- c(" "," ","Title pushes graph down")
title2 <- c(" "," ","Also here graph lower")
```

[image]

Comment: funny enough :) Thanks.